# I can't get boot screen on proscan tablet without visible volume keys

Tags: factory-reset, locked-out

I watched tutorial on youtube however it didn't cover this model proscan PLT1074 that has no volume rockers. It does not turn on as the video. It will turn on when only the power is held down. Once the reset is pressed at the same time it doesn't.resulting in not getting to the proscan start up screen and then to the next screen with the android symbol in the center and followed by the screen that has the wipe/erase all data option. Then the  restore factory settings.option. So we have no password (locked out)   and we need to restart the tablet from fresh (factory reset) by no volume keys  ( I mean there are NO VISIBLE VOLUME BUTTONS ON THE EXTERIOR OF THIS MODEL)  I am unable to progress to the recovery flash mode and can,t boot either.

Comment: Welcome, please [edit] and clarify by "can't access the boot screen", did you mean (1) the tablet doesn't power on? (2) the tablet powers on, but is stuck at a specific screen (which screen? If possible, take a photo and upload it on the question) (3) since the question is also tagged with 'factory-reset', did you mean the Factory Reset Protection where you must enter the previous user's credential? (4) By volume keys, did you mean you can enter recovery/flash mode, but cannot boot normally? Also, if possible, mention the specific device model, otherwise, there's not enough detail to solve it.

Comment: The model is PLT1074G. The youtube tutorial video says to power off put pin in reset hole press button down press power and hold until android symbol appears. It wont turn on as in the video. My daughter was given this tablet without any of the access passwords etc. Trying to factory reset it. We are unable to get the screen to appear where the option to erase data option should appear. By factory reset I mean this is the function we are unable to perform. The tablet doesnt want to power on when the reset button and power are pressed.